# Why is this an example of actuator?

Tags: circuit-analysis, led, actuator

[image]Hi, I know that an actuator is: a component of a machine that is responsible for moving or controlling a mechanism

But how is a simple LED circuit as I’ve attached an actuator example please as there is nothing that is controlled? The led lights when power is supplied

Comment: It is not an actuator. It does not actuate anything. Who says it is?

Comment: When your car's **engine light** comes on, it prompts you to lift the hood to search for the problem. I suppose you could argue that *you're the actuator*, since *you* fix the problem...but that engine light starts the fixing process.

Comment: My teacher said it was- I couldn’t understand why? He said its homework for us to see why. I think glen has explained it well

Comment: Well... light is producing a teeny-tiny pressure. But I doubt it counts. Well, there is also some heat from the resistor. Still hardly an actuator.

Comment: If the prof wants you to reason about something being actuator or not, he should have given you some definition. If not, then you can use the common definition, by which it is *not* an actuator. Unless the drawing is not exactly what was given to you or the question is not exactly what you cited.

Comment: Actuator in a more widely accepted sense means something like a power device which drives something like a motor or belt. The LED could be a actuator but it seems more like a lamp or a device with just states of on and off.

Comment: What level of class is this?  You need different answers for primary school, secondary school, university.

Comment: Hi it’s year 13- that’s the same drawing I was given by the way. I drew it again as it had lots of numbers and letters on it

Comment: remotely related: [Difference between sensors and transducers](https://makersconfidential.blogspot.com/2015/04/difference-between-sensors-and-transducers.html)

Comment: With enough voltage I’ve had LEDs actuate their smoke release.

Answer (score 3):

Actuator is one of those poorly defined words.

In a narrow dictionary definition, I think you would be right. But I can understand where your teacher is coming from. He has generalised an actuator to mean something that is controlled electrically, and outputs something non-electrical (like light for a LED, or mechanical power for a mechanical actuator). It even produces light in a more or less proportional way to the drive current.

If you wanted to build an example of a feedback system (next class, or the one after), then you could use a mechanical actuator to control the position of something, and a potentiometer or other sensor to close the position feedback loop. Or you could use a LED as the 'actuator' and sense the brightness with a photo-diode to close the brightness feedback loop.

Try not to get hung up on insisting on a narrow definition.

> But how is a simple LED circuit as I’ve attached an actuator example please as there is nothing that is controlled?

The light output is controlled.

Comment: *something that is controlled electrically, and outputs something non-electrical* - that would be a transducer. I'd say the more likely possibility that the OP have misunderstood the prof. Or the prof is plainly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this was not a statement that it is an actuator, but it was a question how it could be an actuator.

"to actuate" from the Cambridge dictionary

> to make a machine work or be the reason a person acts in a certain way

This circuit could control ("actuate") something if supplemented with the photodiode or phototransistor.

Comment: You guys are trying to answer the question "why the prof might wrongly think it is an actuator".

Comment: @EugeneSh. let's troubleshoot professor, he is a set of nerves with electrons travelling along them :)

Answer (score 1):

The LED has two signals that could be considered a controlled variable (output signal): 1) the colour, and 2) the intensity.

The colour is fixed by the band-gap energy as is the voltage drop across the diode.

The intensity (\$P_{I}\$) (power out) is determined by the product: \$P_{I} =\eta I_{D}V_{D} \$. \$\eta\$ is the efficiency. Since the diode voltage is constant, the intensity is determined by the current.

I treat the diode current \$I_{D}\$ as the controlling or **actuating signal**. The intensity of the light is the controlled variable. The LED is the plant (that whose behaviour needs controlling). The actuator then is that which applies the actuating signal.

The diode current is produced by the applying a voltage to the series resistor \$R\$.

$$I_{D}=\frac{V_{BAT}-V_{D}}{R}$$

Therefore, from this point of view, **the resistor is the actuator**.

So I don't agree with the *professors explanation* in this case. If the LED's intensity is used to control another system's behaviour, then it could be considered as an actuator.